# Unsupported BMP compression - BMP to JPEG - PIL - Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bmp

I am trying to convert a bmp image to jpeg using the below code.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('/Desktop/xyz.bmp')
new_img = img.resize( (256, 256) )
new_img.save( '/Desktop/abc.png', 'png')
```

While execution am getting the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/widowed_hulk/otokar/image_scraper.py", line 80, in <module>
    img = Image.open('C:/Users/santhosh.solomon/Desktop/bmp/ImageHandler.bmp')   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2609, in open
    im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2599, in _open_core
    im = factory(fp, filename)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 102, in
__init__
    self._open()   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py", line 201, in
_open
    self._bitmap(offset=offset)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py", line 161, in
_bitmap
    raise IOError("Unsupported BMP compression (%d)" % file_info['compression']) OSError: Unsupported BMP compression (1)
```

Image I am trying to convert : https://servis.otokar.com.tr:8083/ImageHandler.ashx?id=6425

can anyone guide me through this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many possible ways i have found the solution with openCV library. This doesn't throw me any compression error and handled conversion like a charm.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(img)
cv2.imwrite(imag_name.replace('.bmp', '.jpg'), image)
```

Thanks for @Mark for his suggestion too. As i have to convert large number of images and openCV seems lite to handle the problem I am going with openCV.

Comment: Well done for working it out and thanks for sharing back with the community. You can accept your own answer as correct, by the way, and snag the points :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's no fault of your own. The image is in the [awkward](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#bmp) Microsoft BMP V3 format with, I believe, RLE compression and I don't believe Pillow can handle that.

You can use **ImageMagick** to re-write the image without that compression in the Terminal like this and then your code will work fine:

```
convert image.bmp -compress none image.bmp
```

But if you are doing that, you may as well use **ImageMagick** to make the PNG too:

```
convert image.bmp result.png
```

---

As an alternative, if you want to use Python, you might try some other library such as `pyvips` - I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. I would try your suggestion and get to you back with the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mark Setchell suggested, `pyvips` *does* open BMPs that are RLE encoded without any error, unlike PIL and cv2 in my testing. I wanted to open RLE encoded BMPs with PIL, so I'm also using numpy, but you don't need to.

```
import os

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def get_old_img(input_image_path):
    # pyvips acts as a substitute for PIL and cv2, because both of those can throw a warning in the terminal with RLE bmps.
    pyvips_img = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(input_image_path, access='sequential')
    np_img = vips2numpy(pyvips_img)
    return Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np_img))

format_to_np_dtype = {
    'uchar': np.uint8,
    'char': np.int8,
    'ushort': np.uint16,
    'short': np.int16,
    'uint': np.uint32,
    'int': np.int32,
    'float': np.float32,
    'double': np.float64,
    'complex': np.complex64,
    'dpcomplex': np.complex128,
}

def vips2numpy(vi):
    return np.ndarray(buffer=vi.write_to_memory(),
                        dtype=format_to_np_dtype[vi.format],
                        shape=[vi.height, vi.width, vi.bands])

get_old_img("input.bmp").show()
```

I'm not sure if anyone else will have issues getting pyvips to work by installing it via pip when trying to import it as it caused the error `OSError: cannot load library 'C:\dev\vips\vips-dev-8.6\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll'` for me, but you can fix that by ***both*** installing pyvips with pip and by unzipping the latest version of `vips-dev-w64-all.zip` from https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases and updating the `vipshome` string in `load_vips_end()`.

```
def load_vips_env():
    vipshome = 'c:\\vips-dev-8.10\\bin'
    os.environ['PATH'] = vipshome + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

load_vips_env()

import pyvips
```